# Как удалить все записи с ::deleteAll() в yii2

Tags: php, yii2, activerecord

В таблице хранятся выбранные пользователем данные. Среди прочих в таблице есть поле `day` и `news_date`. `Day` хранится в целочисленном формате (например, 9), news_date в формате int (timestamp) (например 1502229600 - это Tue, 08 Aug 2017 22:00:00 GMT).

Есть форма с кучей групп radioButton при помощи которой пользователь выбирает данные, которые затем попадут в таблицу. Выглядит она вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Выбранные новости отправляют в контроллер где их обрабатывает цикл:

`foreach ($text as $id => $newsText)` (здесь `$text` - массив с выбранными данными, `$id` - id новости и `$newsText` - текст новости) заполняют нужные поля таблицы (примерно так `$model->id_news = $id;`) и сохраняются в базу.

Проблема: выбрана может быть только одна новость из столбца за один год. Т.е если пользователь выбирает новость из левого столбца "2017" то необходимо удалить все новости за 2017-й год (news_date преобразую в год) день этой новости в поле `day` из таблицы и сохранить запись заново.

Пытаюсь сделать как то вот так

```
foreach ($text as $id => $newsText) {
     //ищу в таблице запись по $id 
      $thisDayNew = $model::findOne(["id_news" => (int) $id]);
    //а дальше не знаю что и как делать :(
      if ((int) $thisDayNew->id_news != (int) $id) {
    //удалить все новости $id которых не подошло
   //и добавить новую
    $model = new ThisDay;
    $model::deleteAll
(["FROM_UNIXTIME(news_date, '%Y')"
 => 
date("Y", $tdNew->news->cdate),
 "day" =>
 date('j', mktime(0, 0, 0, 
 date('m', $tdNew->news_date),
 date('d', $tdNew->news_date),
 date('Y', $tdNew->news_date)))]);
   } else {
//просто вставляю новую запись (это сделано уже:))
}
```

Пояснение:
В `date('Y', $tdNew->news_date)` я получаю дату публикации новости

Но этот код никак не срабатывает. Как реализовать данный функционал удаления?

P.S

`var_dump($thisDayNew);` подсказывает что `$thisDayNew` хранит массив как на изображении ниже

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Доброе утро. Что-то путано у Вас всё. Пользователь выбирает одну новость за определённый год и должны удалиться все новости за выбранный год? А какая запись заново сохраниться должна?

Comment: @slo_nik да, за выбранный год удаляется запись (все - это по сути одна) и добовляется выбранная, но удаляются записи только в случае если выбранных новостей нет в базе, тогда им можно просто заголовок обновить по необходимости. Сейчас это работает так: можно выбрать новость за 2017 год, добавить её в базу, вернуться на эту форму и снова добавить еще одну новость за 2017 год, а должно быть, чтобы прежняя запись (если выбрана не она) удалялась из базы и добовлялась новая. И вам доброе утро, но у нас уже вечер :)

Comment: Всё равно, что-то слишком запутано у Вас. Попробую перечитать, но...

Comment: @slo_nik просто если в форме за 2017 год выбрана запись которой нет в таблице, то нужно удалить все записи за 2017 год и день этой записи и сохранить выбранную :) вот условие которое это проверять по идее должно 
`if ((int) $tdNew->id_news != (int) $id) `

Comment: Тогда откуда вообще берётся новость, если её нет в таблице?

Comment: @slo_nik выборка делается в контроллере из другой таблицы. Могу дополнить вопрос кодом запроса в эту базу, если это нужно

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74804/discussion-between-slo-nik-and--).

Answer (score 0):

Проблема оказалась в самом условии и немного в том, что следовало за ним. Исправленный код выглядит так:

```
//если массив пустой, значит выбранной новости нет в таблице ThisDay
if (!$thisDayNew) {
$model = new ThisDay;

//следовательно ищем по id выбранной новости в другой таблице
$newsM = News::findOne(["id" => $id]);
$model::deleteAll(["FROM_UNIXTIME(news_date, '%Y')"

//и подставляем данные уже из нее, где они нужны
    => date("Y", $newsM->cdate_int),
    "day" =>
    date('j', mktime(0, 0, 0,
            date('m', $newsM->cdate_int),
            date('d', $newsM->cdate_int),
            date('Y', $newsM->cdate_int)))]);
//тут код сохранения новых данных
}
```